# How to get whitespace-mode enabled only for certain modes

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

I'm trying to get emacs `whitespace-mode` enabled automatically only in certain modes.  According to the documentation, enabling `global-whitespace-mode` and setting the `whitespace-global-modes` variable should do exactly that.  But I can't get it to work correctly.

In my `.emacs.el` I have:

```
(require 'whitespace)
(global-whitespace-mode t)
(setq whitespace-global-modes '(c-mode c++-mode))
```

but the definition of `whitespace-global-modes` seems to be ignored; `global-whitespace-mode` is enabled in every buffer.  I know that I've got the variable name correctly, because `C-h v whitespace-global-modes` tells me:

```
whitespace-global-modes's value is (c-mode c++mode)

Documentation:
Modes for which global `whitespace-mode' is automagically turned on.
...
```

So what am I doing wrong?  Have I misunderstood the purpose of `whitespace-global-modes`?

I'm running emacs 23.2.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the commands in my `.emacs.el` *were* (almost) working after all.  What confused me was that "WS" appears in the modeline of all buffers, even though only C and C++ buffers were getting the effect of `whitespace-mode`, as desired.

The other problem was that I had a typo: `c++mode` rather than `c++-mode`.

Comment: Hmm, then what is the meaning of WS in the mode line? I'm confused. WS for global, ws for local... that kind of thing?

Answer (score 5):

Apparently the meaning of whitespace-global-modes is very different from what you (and I) understand.

How about trying

```
(require 'whitespace)

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 
  (function (lambda ()
              (whitespace-mode t))))
```

and repeating the same thing for c++-mode?

Comment: I think that would have worked too, but I really wanted to get `whitespace-global-modes` to work.  I guess one advantage of your solution is that "WS" wouldn't appear in the modeline for buffers where it wasn't doing anything.

Comment: Yes, WS versus ws was very confusing for me, too.

Comment: Thank you very much!  This solves the issue of newly created files and the scratch buffer not adhering to the global definition.  Adding hooks for each mode (as described in Mr. Sevinç's answer) eliminates the need to manually turn on whitespacing for new files and/or the scratch buffer.  The global behavior was confusing because the global definition worked for existing files that were opened with the application, but not new files or the scratch buffer.